# TF237085 - Item has an unknown error that caused BatchSave to fail

Tags: .net, azure-devops

i have a problem with request review. When we submit review to other person, an error appears:

```
Could not save work item 0: 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.BatchSaveFailedException: 
TF237085: Item has an unknown error that caused BatchSave to fail
```

I use Visual Studio Online and Visual Studio 2013 Premium.

Comment: Do you have the permission to create  work item?

Comment: Could you tell me where I check this option?:)

Comment: From the VSTS Web Portal, Project\Settings\Areas, Right click on the project and select security, make sure "Edit work items in this node" is allow. Or you can simple try to create an work item to see if the work item can be created successfully.

Comment: And you also need to check if the reviewer you assigned has the access to the code.

Comment: It doesn't work:( I can create new work item, but still can't request review, all user have allow permission to "edit work item in this node". I have second project in TFS Online, but I can request review in second project :( settings is all the same  @Eddie - MSFT

Answer (score 0):

I just install the VS2013 and can reproduce this issue too. I also try with VS2015 and get following error:

> Could not save work item 0:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.BatchSaveFailedException:
>   TF401319: Rule evaluation failed for field Reviewed By.

So this looks like an issue from VSTS, I have help you submit a feedback on Microsoft Connect Page, you can track it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2266743

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that should be resolved with our next deployment.  Sorry for the inconvenience.